# How to read office 2010 excelfile using openpyxl without changing style

Tags: python, openpyxl

i am new in python and i want to read office 2010 excel file without changing its style. Currently its working fine but changing date format. i want it as they are in excel file.

Answer (score 1):

> i want it as they are in excel file.

A date is recorded in an Excel file (both 2007+ XLSX files and earlier XLS files) as a **floating point number of days** (and fraction thereof) since some date in 1899/1900 or 1904. Only the "number format" that is recorded against the cell can be used to distinguish whether a date or a number was intended.

You will need to be able to retrieve the actual float value and the "number format" and apply the format to the float value. If the "number format" being used is one of the standard ones, this should be easy enough to do. Customised number formats are another matter. Locale-dependant formats likewise.

To get detailed help, you will need to give examples of what raw data you have got and what you want to "see" and how it is now being presented ("changing date format").

Comment: i have date value in one column like 02/Jan/1988 and in another column i have value like 12/01/2012. i want value same as they are in xlsx file. but it returning like 2008-01-28 00:00:00

Comment: So the software is producing the date in something maybe close enough to ISO standard date format. Doesn't matter. Irrespective of the starting point, you need to get a tuple (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fraction of second maybe) and the number format and push them through your own formatter code. And you mean "same as they are displayed by Excel", NOT "same as they are in xlsx file"